# Save File Problem

Tags: gnome

18.04.3 LTS
Gnome 3.28.2
FireFox 71
Abiword 3.0.2
LibreOffice 6.0.7.3
Ryzen 5 16GB RAM

I cannot save a document or file in any application. When I select "save" or "save as" instead of getting a save dialog box where I name the file, choose the location, and select the save button I get a file navigation window with NO name file or save buttons or functions - all it allows me to do is navigate the file system and file types shown (it is similar to "Files" window but not the same). I cannot name new documents. Gnome?

Comment: It could be because you're trying to save to a location you don't have write privileges to.  Also if your system has detected fs errors and has re-mounted the fs as RO (read-only), it's done to preventing more problems as the fs needs check first (`fsck`) - but there are many possibilities which we can only guess at from your description thus far.

Comment: Saving to Home Documents

Comment: Oh, it does save the doc in Home Documents as "untitled" using Control-S.

Comment: The dialog box was probably waiting for you to enter a filename, once entered you may find the SAVE button is no longer greyed (or however it appears with your theme).

Comment: What dialog box? I said I did not get a dialog box - the point of my question. It is not a permission problem, I can write to the location as Control-S proves. I can also drag and drop files to the location.

Comment: I get the exact same file navigation window in every application when I try to save, it is not the application dialog save box, it is a system window that does not have a name file or save fuction/field/button.

Comment: Sorry I missed that **key** piece of info; my guess is you've added a theme or code that tries to alter the appearance of GNOME that wasn't intended or tested to work with Ubuntu's GNOME 3.28  (eg. something intended for pop/elementary/etc which expects modified code/setup to standard ubuntu/gnome), whatever was changed before this is (particularly prior session(s) before logout/login or reboot) is clue but we're limited to what information you provide.  I would try using `gnome-tweaks` to modify themes etc & see if it helps/hurts/does-nothing..